# Where are large cache files stored for Google Chrome on OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cache

Where are the large cache files for Google Chrome are saved in OS X?

For files less than 50 MB it's under `/Library/Caches/Google...`

But for files more than 50 MB, it used to be in `/var/...`.

It's not there any more. Did Google change something?

Comment: I loaded some large flash videos from YouTube and the cache files created in `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache` were never larger than 26 MB, Chrome (latest version on 10.8.2) seems to avoid creating large cache files. What makes you think that files larger than 50 MB, if ever created, are saved elsewhere? I couldn't find any reference to this behavior in the Chrome support pages.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has changed the location. I have noticed the same behavior and the old location var/folders. . . no longer contains the large temporary flash files. This is a hidden location which used to store flash files until the window with the file link was closed. You will not find a reference in the support pages.

Comment: You may consider improving your answer by adding exact location and maybe some more details.